# Ethereum RPC endpoint with trace_block supported

Tags: clients

I am trying to collect block data from block 15600000. These are post-merge blocks and thus are not supported by any Erigon clients that I am aware of. I find the Erigon clients using [Ethernodes](https://ethernodes.org/). The rest of the clients have synced nodes that support Ethereum 2, but the problem is that those clients e.g. GETH do not support trace mode. For example, when I send the following request to a Nethermind RPC endpoint it will not work:

```
r = SESSION.get(
            f"http://{ip_address}:8545/",
            timeout=2,
            json={
                "method": "trace_block",
                "params": [15500000],
                "id": 1,
                "jsonrpc": "2.0"
            },
            headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'}
        )
```

I tried to set up a personal endpoint using QuickNode. But it requires the Build plan to enable trace mode, in other words, I can't use the free plan.

Are there any other clients or custom endpoints that support trace mode? As far as I know, the only clients that have trace mode are Erigon and OpenEthereum which is archived.

Answer (score 2):

[Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) offers [Erigon nodes with debug and trace](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/enable-debug-trace-apis-for-your-ethereum-node), but starting from the growth plan and a dedicated node, or on elastic nodes starting from the business plan; not on the free tier, unfortunately.

Keep in mind that `trace_block` is unique to the Erigon client, [OpenEthereum](https://github.com/openethereum/openethereum) is deprecated.

You can find more info about it in the [Chainstack dev portal - trace_block](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-trace_block).

Comment: Thanks, but I would much prefer a free node.